# How to install coturn to mac

Tags: macos, coturn

How to install coturn on mac

I made all of the steps as described

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/CoturnConfig

But receiving this errors

```
In file included from src/apps/oauth/oauth.c:41:
src/apps/common/apputils.h:34:10: fatal error: 'event2/event.h' file not found
#include <event2/event.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from src/apps/common/apputils.c:34:
src/apps/common/apputils.h:34:10: fatal error: 'event2/event.h' file not found
#include <event2/event.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
src/apps/common/ns_turn_utils.c:35:10: fatal error: 'event2/http.h' file not found
#include <event2/http.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [bin/turnutils_oauth] Error 1
```

I am totally new for coturn, Please help, what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, for MacOs you have to install third party libraries before installation of coturn

```
$ wget https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz
As root, build and install the library with the usual:

$ tar xvfz libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz
$ cd libevent-2.0.21-stable
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```